# Hiding form after submitting and showing actual content of page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

I want to create one product page , on nav-bar when user clicks on product before showing all product it should show one form and after filling form then and then only all products will be shown to the customer.

I am trying to do this in php but cant find solution ,

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
$('#output').hide();  
e.preventDefault();
// Or with: return false;
```

});

instead of id #output i want to the actual page after submitting
please help me to get this solve

Comment: Pretty broad question, given no code to work with.

Comment: first show the code or related example

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a code writing service, you know? We'd suggest that you put the code you've written so far, and show us where you've gotten stuck. Then we could provide helpful suggestions and solutions to your problem.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience i will try to send code ASAP, as i am newbe i was not aware of it

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use [Ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) if you don't want to redirect the page after the submit.

Example of HTML:

```
<form>
    <!-- here your form -->
</form>
<div id="other-products"> <!-- this css style would be display: none; -->
    <!-- here you show your other products -->
</div>
```

Example of jQuery:

```
$("form").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        url: "url/to/php/file.php",
        type: "POST",
        success: function(res) {
            $("#other-products").fadeIn();
        }
    });
});
```

In the URL you give, you will have to make your PHP scripts and then, return something if you needed (keep in mind the dataType you are giving). That something will be `res` in the example given.